# php convert floating point to long (convert to string to pass to a xml function)

Tags: php, math, floating-point, long-integer

PHP converts a large number to floating point which I need in "long" format to pass to a soap xml api.

```
((round(time()/(60*15))*60*15)+(30*60))*1000
```

This gives the result:

```
1.28E+12
```

Whereas, what I need is:

```
"1280495700000"
```

in order to pass to the api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

format it using number_format()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
sprintf('%u',$number);
```

But if you're about to lose precision you need, look at the [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions (`bcadd`, `bcdiv` and the like). They will keep precision, and give you back strings.